# Button floating on QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QWidget which shows some images from the USB camera, is it possible to add some button in the widget so it will auto resize/move with the window?

I have tried to simply use new operator to create a button, and set its parent as my QWidget, however, it always show up at the left corner of my widget, How could I put it to other places and make it auto resize?

Comment: Did you try use layouts?

Comment: I tried, but dont know how to use layout to make the button floating above my widget...

Comment: What do you mean "floating", do you want that widget was a part of mainWidget or you want that this widget was as a separate window?

Comment: I want it to be apart of it, just like the zoom in /out button of google map...

Comment: I understood it that you want widget on same window but above all other widgets. So try to add this widget as you did, setGeometry which you want, and call `thisWidget->raise();` Your widget will be above all other widgets like slider on Google Maps above on map. Is it what you want?

Comment: Good. In this case, I posted this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course window is `2D`, but there is also `z-value` or `z-order`, which show some widget above all other widgets. You can change z-value with [`QWidget::raise()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#raise)

> Raises this widget to the top of the parent widget's stack.
>
> After this call the widget will be visually in front of any
>   overlapping sibling widgets.

Comment: see also: https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/65479-Is-there-a-way-exist-to-add-Floating-button-inside-QWidget